# Modify Get method to get data using Name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem like this. I am Creating a Nodejs application using MongoDB with mongoose. There is a collection in my database as Employee. Objects of that collection have some attributes such as id, name, position, office, Salary.

I have created a node function get employees using id like this.

```
router.get('/:id',function (req, res) {
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)){
        return res.status(400).send('No record with given id :$(req.params.id)');
    }

    Employee.findById(req.params.id, function (err, doc) {
        if(!err){
            res.send(doc);
        }

        else{
            console.log('Error in Retriving Employee:'+JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        }

    });
});
```

I want to modify this function to find the employee using the name. I search and tried lots of examples and, I was unable to find a suitable method to do it.

One way that I tried is like this.

```
router.get('employee/:name'),function (req, res) {
    Employee.find(req.params.name, function (err, doc) {
        if(!err){
            res.send(doc);
        }

        else{
            console.log('Error in Retriving Employee:'+JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        }
    });
```

}

But it is not giving the result it just gives me an error like this.

```
Cannot GET /employees/employee/Tharindu
```

In the console window, it showing me like this.

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

With this,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Can Someone help me to solve this problem? Thank You.

Comment: what output/ error log do you get from your code? `db.employee.find({'name': nameVariable});` is one way of doing it but if I have more information, I could be more helpful! :)

Comment: It giving me a error like this

Comment: `Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback`.

Comment: `Cannot GET /employees/employee/Tharindu`

Comment: change your meta security tag as well: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />`

Comment: How to change it with node js file. I am new to express

Comment: see the answer I've posted below the comments.

Comment: About *Content Security Policy*, you should use [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) package as a basic security setup for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something might be wrong with the way that you are tying to call
the collection in the database:

```
 Employee.find(req.params.name, function (err, doc) {
        if(!err){
            res.send(doc);
        }
```

I really think that you should do it with something similar to this:

```
   app.get('employee/:name', function (req, res){
     db.open(function(err,db){ 
         db.collection('employee', function(err, collection) {
             collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                 console.log(items);
                 res.send(items);
             });
         });
     });
});
```

This will return a result of an array `collection.find().toArray` with the information inside the collection.

Also, using the path `employee/:name` might not be one of the best practices.

Comment: Then what is the best way to pass the name to that method?